# Java 8 - Group a list and find the count

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of result. I need to find the passed results count. But there is a relation between some items in list. For Example. I have list like

```
1.0 - false
2.0 - true
3.0 - false
4.0 - true
1.1 - true
3.1 - true
```

Then the passed count should be 2 and not the 4. Because I want to group the list based on id (1,1.2,1.3,1.xx in to single group) and mark it as pass if all the items in the group is pass . I have tried group using `groupingBy` and I have got a map of my expected behavior. I can iterate the map and get the count. But I want to know is there any way I can do this simply using Java 8.

```
public class Main {

static class Resultx {

    double id = 1;

    Boolean passed = false;

    public void setId(double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setAsPassed() {
        this.passed = true;
    }

    public Boolean getPassed() {
        return passed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + " - " + getPassed();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Resultx> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        Resultx result = new Resultx();
        result.setId(i);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result.setAsPassed();
        }
        results.add(result);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i += 2) {
        Resultx result = new Resultx();
        result.setId(i + .1);
        result.setAsPassed();
        results.add(result);
    }
    System.out.println(results.size());
    results.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println(results.stream().filter(Resultx::getPassed).count());
    System.out.println(results.stream().filter(e -> !e.getPassed()).count());
    System.out.println(results.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (int) (r.getId()))));
}
}
```

Output

```
Total count - 6
1.0 - false
2.0 - true
3.0 - false
4.0 - true
1.1 - true
3.1 - true
Total pass count  - 4
Total fail count - 2
{1=[1.0 - false, 1.1 - true], 2=[2.0 - true], 3=[3.0 - false, 3.1 - true], 4=[4.0 - true]}
```

I want Overall pass count and overall fail count. which is 2 and 2

Comment: what about the ones that go above `.5`, so is `1.6` treated as `1` or `2`?

Comment: Using a `double` for an ID looks suspicious. So does using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` for passed. Do you plan to support `null` values for it?

Comment: Should be fairly easy. Iterate the values as Key value pairs where key is `(int) floatValue;` and value as a boolean operation - `existingValueIfany && newBooleanValue`. Now you would have K, V pairs with   number and boolean value. Filter only `true` values and get count. I'm using mobile and thus couldn't type answer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some strange things about your code, like using a `double` ID, which you just cast to `int` in your grouping operation or using a `Boolean` for you `passed` property instead of just `boolean`. Using the reference type `Boolean`, opens the opportunity to be `null`, which you would have to handle, if this possibility is intended. Otherwise, just use `boolean`.

It’s also not clear, what result you actually want. The example is not sufficient to describe it.

If you only want to count the groups, where `true` means “all where true” and `false` means “some where `false`”, you can do it as simple as

```
Map<Boolean,Long> counts = results.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(r -> (int)r.getId(), Resultx::getPassed, Boolean::logicalAnd),
        m -> m.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(b -> b, Collectors.counting()))
    ));
```

If you want to count the elements of the groups, it gets more complicated.

```
int totalPassedCount = results.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (int)r.getId(),
        Collector.of(() -> new Object() { int count = 0; boolean pass = true; },
            (o, r) -> { o.count++; o.pass &= r.getPassed(); },
            (x, y) -> { x.count += y.count; x.pass &= y.pass; return x; },
            o -> o.pass? o.count: 0
        )),
        (Map<Integer,Integer> x) -> x.values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()
    ));
System.out.println(totalPassedCount);
```

This uses a custom collector as *downstream* collector for `groupingBy`. This custom collector collects into an object holding the element count and whether all elements passed, then, in a finishing step, it replaces these object with the count, if all elements of the group passed or zero if not. Then, a finishing step is added to the `groupingBy` collector which will sum up all these values.

---

Above solution is for getting the passed counts, as you asked for in the beginning of your question. Since you’re asking for both at the end, you could use

```
Map<Boolean,Integer> counts = results.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (int)r.getId(),
        Collector.of(() -> new Object() { int count = 0; boolean pass = true; },
            (o, r) -> { o.count++; o.pass &= r.getPassed(); },
            (x, y) -> { x.count += y.count; x.pass &= y.pass; return x; }
        )),
        m -> m.values().stream().collect(
            Collectors.partitioningBy(o -> o.pass, Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.count)))
    ));
```

for getting both.

Or, as it’s tricky to get the intended rule from a single example,

```
Map<Boolean,Integer> counts = results.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (int)r.getId(),
        Collector.of(() -> new Object() { int passed, failed; },
            (o, r) -> { if(r.getPassed()) o.passed++; else o.failed++; },
            (x, y) -> { x.passed += y.passed; x.failed += y.failed; return x; }
        )),
        m -> m.values().stream()
            .filter(o -> o.passed == 0 || o.failed == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(o -> o.failed==0,
                Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.failed==0? o.passed: o.failed)))
    ));
```

this will only count `passed` and `failed`, if all elements of a group passed or failed. But since you said, you’d expect `2` and `2`, you may remove the `.filter(o -> o.passed == 0 || o.failed == 0)` line. Then, it will count `passed` only if all elements of the groups passed, but count all `failed`, even when some elements of the group passed. Then, you’d get `2` and `2` as result.

Comment: The reason for double part is, assume there are tasks that has sub tasks, so it wouldbe 1.1,1.2....1.12 . The Result object would hold the results of the Tasks. I would need to print them in an order so went for that.

Comment: Yeah, I would have gone for boolean , I wont want null values, will change. thanks for that. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes I want **true means “all where true” and false means “some where false”**

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
 Map<Boolean, Long> collect = results.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> (int) (r.getId()))).values()
                    .stream().map(l -> l.stream().allMatch(p -> p.getPassed()))
                    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(k -> k, Collectors.counting()));

            System.out.println(collect);
```

Which display:

```
{false=2, true=2}
```

Comment: The disadvantage is that this will collect all group elements into `List`s first, just to perform a logical and of the `passed` property afterwards. This reduction can be done right in the first grouping step without the intermediate list creation.

Comment: Thanks @SEY_91 , though your answer straight to the point and it is what I expected, purely for the above point by Holger, I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy, just sort the results based on the test numbers, and then count each group individually. The sorting shouldn't be that computationally complex as long as you are dealing with less than million(s) of tests.

And if a single 'test' within the 'group' fails, the group as a whole fails, and then just have a struct to store the results of each grouping.

Comment: how will the give you the total results of `false` and `true`?

Comment: Depending on what exactly' you mean, you can count both in different structures, 1 for total 'overall' (two ints: overall_true, overall_false) and one for 'total within each group. For simplicity's sake I'd just use a hashmap (not ideal, but first collection most people learn) to store the values of each group's count.(checking beforehand that I'm not over-writing values)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this is the easiest way, but:

```
Map<Double, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1.0D, false);
    map.put(2.0D, true);
    map.put(2.1D, true);
    map.put(1.2D, true);

    Map<Boolean, Long> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                x -> Arrays.asList(Math.round(x.getKey()), x.getValue()),
                Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                e -> (Boolean) e.getKey().get(1),
                Collectors.counting()));


  System.out.println(result); // {false=1, true=2}
```

Comment: You are just counting the groups, ignoring the element counts of your first grouping operation completely. I.e., you produce the groups `[1, false], [2, true], [1, true]`, resulting in one `false` and two `true` value.

Comment: @Holger isn't this result what the OP expects? But I agree otherwise on the useless counting

Comment: I don’t know. The OP’s description is really ambiguous. There are so many things that happen to be `2`… But if the OP only want to count the groups, it can be done *much simpler*. I’ve added a solution for that case at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if *Java 8* collection API would be the easiest way to go, but here down an implementation allowing to count the number of positive and negative results:

```java
System.out.println(
              results.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(result -> (int) (result.getId())))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .map(v -> v.stream().allMatch(Resultx::getPassed))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b, Collectors.counting()))
        );
```

Comment: Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068710/2711488).